# How to prevent button double click

Tags: android, onclicklistener, android-button, double-click

I have a button in my activity. When the user clicks on the button, progress is shown and a request is sent to the server, after receiving a response to the request, the progress is hided and the next activity is opened.
However, if the user has time to press the button several times, two or more activities will open.
For preventing double click I use DebouncedOnClickListener. Here is my code:

```
abstract class DebouncedOnClickListener protected constructor() : View.OnClickListener {
    private val minimumIntervalMillis: Long = 1000
    private val lastClickMap: MutableMap<View, Long>

    abstract fun onDebouncedClick(v: View?)

    override fun onClick(clickedView: View) {
        val previousClickTimestamp = lastClickMap[clickedView]
        val currentTimestamp = SystemClock.uptimeMillis()
        lastClickMap[clickedView] = currentTimestamp
        if (previousClickTimestamp == null || abs(currentTimestamp - previousClickTimestamp) > minimumIntervalMillis) {
            onDebouncedClick(clickedView)
        }
    }

    init {
        lastClickMap = WeakHashMap()
    }
}
```

This method works in many cases. However, the request can be processed for an unknown amount of time. And the user can click on the button while the request is completed, the progress will be closed and the process of opening the next activity will start. I do not know how long a new activity can be launched, and at this moment another click on the button can occur, which will subsequently lead to the opening of two activities.

How can you avoid double clicking until the activity opens, please help me.

P.S. Even when I try to disable the button, double-clicking can still happen during the launch of the activity

Comment: i don't really understand the problem you're having, how can someone press it twice ? if someone presses a button, disable it, show loading, wait for the service call to complete, then handle the response of the api call, isn't it that simple ?

Comment: Disable the button after single click, re-enable it on API response

Comment: I prefer to use the single tap listener https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener and disable the button que the click is trigger

Answer (score 0):

- Just paste this on button click

  button.setEnabled(false);

Answer (score 0):

You can use a boolean flag like following.

```kotlin
private val onClicked: Boolean = false

override fun onClick(clickedView: View) {
    if(!onClicked) {
        onClicked = true
        // Do something
        onClicked = false
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add required functions in Utils and wherever it's required call it by passing view as parameter.

const val DIGIT_THOUSAND = 1000

```
fun preventMultipleTap(view: View) {
    preventMultipleTap(view, DIGIT_THOUSAND.toLong())
}

fun preventMultipleTap(view: View, delayInMillis: Long) {
    view.isEnabled = false
    view.postDelayed({ view.isEnabled = true }, delayInMillis)
}
```